# unarchiving and uncompressing a qcow2.bk.gz file

Tags: linux, centos

can you pleaes suggest me how I can unarchive and uncompress the following file:

**new-vm.qcow2.bk.gz**

Comment: What generates those files? What's the output of `zcat new-vm.qcow2.bk.gz | file -`?

Comment: In any case, "qcow2" (and "vm") suggests it's a virtual disk image. If it's files stored in any of the file systems stored there if any you want  to extract, that will depend a lot on how the VM is deployed (what type of OS, of partitioning, LVM used? what filesystem, etc).

Comment: I want to make it as new-vm.qcow2. i used the gunzip new-vm.qcow2.bk.gz  command and then it became new-vm.qcow2.bk

Comment: Then what does `file new-vm.qcow2.bk` return? I suspect it's just a qcow2 file, but something/somebody added a `.bk` extension to indicate it was a backup.

Comment: Agree with Stéphane. I would just try to use guestfish to check if image contains a consistent disk structure. see http://libguestfs.org/guestfish.1.html